# Set variable in a single PowerShell line

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting

Can any of you let me know how to state a variable in a PowerShell line? Just like I could do using PowerShell ISE I would like to be able to do so via the plain console.

Comment: `$variable = 'value'`. The language syntax doesn't change when you run it in the ISE.

Comment: What do you mean by "state a variable"? Like `$x = 1`?

Answer (score 3):

You can assign values to a PowerShell variable by combining a variable name, an assignment operator, and an expression. Here is a simple example:

```
>> $a = 1 + 1
```

If you want to populate multiple variables with the same value, you can save some typing as in the example below:

```
>> $a = $b = $c = 1
```

You can also define multiple variables with different values on one line:

```
>> $a, $b, $c = 1, 2, 3
```

To display the value of a variable, you don’t need a special command as in many other programming languages; entering the variable name is enough. This works in a script and on a command prompt.

```
>> $c
```

To take values from user, similar to Python `input()` function you can use:

```
$Number = Read-Host "Please enter a number"
```

Read the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to get the job done. I just set the variable and end it with a semi-colon. Then I can go on with scripting.

Thank you all.